# What are suitable examples of “a simple permutation function instead of a table stored in program memory” for Pearson hashing?

Tags: algorithm, hash

The article [“Pearson hashing”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_hashing) on Wikipedia contains the following information:

> One of its drawbacks when compared with other hashing algorithms designed for 8-bit processors is the suggested 256 byte lookup table, which can be prohibitively large for a small microcontroller with a program memory size on the order of hundreds of bytes. A workaround to this is to use a simple permutation function instead of a table stored in program memory. However, using a too simple function, such as `T[i] = 255-i` partly defeats the usability as a hash function as anagrams will result in the same hash value; using a too complex function, on the other hand, will affect speed negatively. Using a function rather than a table also allows extending the block size. Such function naturally have to be bijective, like their table variants.

The question: does there exist a function that fits the description above, but does not require generating prime numbers and does not depend on primality in any way? If yes, what functions can I consider?

Comment: Something like `hash ^= (byte * C + hash) % 256;` should suffice, where `C` is a constant and `C > 0`.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen: Such function will not "look random" in comparison with the "standard" Pearson hashing. For example, if `byte` is odd, `C` is odd and `hash` is odd, then `(byte * C + hash) % 256` is always even.

Comment: Ofcourse it will not "look random". Why is this a requirement? If you're not using a "randomized" table your option is to use a linear generator which is deterministic and non-random by nature. The "table" of such a generator will, as you say, not look random but the resulting hash will look "random enough". On the other hand a table is not random either since every value is unique. Only the order of the values can be considered random but then again the order of such a table could be exactly as the order of the numbers generated by a linear generator.

Comment: When I wrote [will not "look random"], I meant that modifying the last byte of the input by the operation `lastByte = (lastByte + 1) % 256` leads to alternately odd and even outputs. This is different from the properties of the "standard" Pearson hashing.

Comment: A simple idea to replace Pearson hash might be to accumulate `hash = (ror hash) ^ byte` where `ror` is a roll right operator.  

A permutation function in lieu of the Pearson lookup table could be a linear feedback shift register (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register) like xorshift8.  You take the input byte and find the next value in the lfsr sequence, optionally inserting the 0 fixed point at some arbitrary point in the seq.